# Adding pluggin to a wordpress static font page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, static, frontpage

I would like to add a social widget to a Wordpress static frontpage. Hoe do I go about doing this? Please help! Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit vague. By "social widget", are you trying to add:

- A Twitter widget - https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets
- A Facebook plugin (like box, activity feed, recommendations, etc) - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/
- A custom WordPress social widget
- something else?

Most of those just require copying the code that the site provides you. If you'll be more specific, I'll do my best to help you out! :)